# uninitialized constant AuthenticationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, jwt

I am trying to authenticate an User using JWT Authentication and I'm having problem.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "gabriel",
  "username": "gabriel_carneiro",
  "email": "gabriel.bsb98@gmail.com",
  "password_digest": "$2a$12$7K.Z/ixpVM.lOkINboFW5.tvVlPYFnbMTEreVrrR4IClAL.70IQkO",
  "created_at": "2020-06-17T11:13:27.116Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-06-17T11:13:27.116Z"
}
```

Then I need to authenticate it. I'm sending it using Postman :

**email** : gabriel.bsb98@gmail.com
**password** : 12345678

I received this error message :

```
 {   "status": 500,   "error": "Internal Server Error",   "exception":
 "#<NameError: uninitialized constant
 AuthenticationController::JsonWebToken>",   "traces": {
     "Application Trace": [
       {
         "exception_object_id": 70261772705960,
         "id": 0,
         "trace": "app/controllers/authentication_controller.rb:8:in `login'"
       }
```

It accuses an error in line 8 at Authentication Controller. This is my Authenctication Controller :

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorize_request, except: :login

    # POST /auth/login
    def login
      @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      if @user&.authenticate(params[:password])
        token = JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: @user.id)
        time = Time.now + 24.hours.to_i
        render json: { token: token, exp: time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"),
                       username: @user.username }, status: :ok
      else
        render json: { error: 'unauthorized' }, status: :unauthorized
      end
    end

    private

    def login_params
      params.permit(:email, :password)
    end

end
```

How can I solve this problem ?\
Ps : This is the tutorial that I read https://medium.com/binar-academy/rails-api-jwt-authentication-a04503ea3248

Comment: What if you do `::JsonWebToken.encode`?

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I tried token = ::JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: @user.id)
But didn't work

Comment: https://medium.com/@shalinibhagat/thanks-for-this-article-it-2c2a67db4366

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your class `"AuthenticationController::JsonWebToken"` is not declared and Rails want to search it in `AuthenticationController` class' body.

After you've placed the `JsonWebToken` class in lib folder, make sure the autoload path is added in `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.autoload_paths << “#{Rails.root}/lib”
```

as @Eyeslandic said.

Answer (score 2):

[You will in all likelihood](https://medium.com/@shalinibhagat/thanks-for-this-article-it-2c2a67db4366) have to add this line to `config/application.rb`

```rb
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.autoload_paths << “#{Rails.root}/lib” 
end
```